# Multiple args in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

What do multiple arguments like this do in x86 assembly.  For example these two instructions:

`mov  -0x4(%edi,%esi,4),%eax`

`lea    (%edi,%esi,4),%ebx`

I'm reluctant to post all of the assembly code because it's for a university project and my teacher probably wouldn't want me posting this online. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked up the opcodes yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first instruction loads the (32 bit) value at the address: `(%edi + %esi * 4) - 4`, into `%eax`. The second sets `%ebx` to: `(%edi + %esi * 4)`.

Comment: More generally, `displacement(base,index,scale)` is the address `base + scale*index + displacement`, and is frequently (but not only) used to access arrays. `base` and `index` must be register values, and `scale` and `displacement` are immediates.  The only allowed values for `scale` are 1, 2, 4, or 8.

Comment: @hopup - it's difficult to construct a C statement that is guaranteed to correspond to a particular instruction. These instructions often appear in loops, and array indexing as Stephen mentions.